# Change domain of Kentico CurrentContact cookie

Tags: cookies, kentico

I have a Kentico installation at `sub.mydomain.com`. The CurrentContact cookie is created using a domain of `sub.mydomain.com`. I want the cookie to be able to be read by other subdmains like `app.mydomain.com`.

Is there a way to accomplish this? Is there a `web.config` setting or a system event in which we can change the cookie domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a cookie is issued for `.mydomain.com` then it will be accessible on all sub domains i.e. `sub.` and `app.` but not vice versa. Technically is `sub.mydomain.com` and `app.mydomain.com` are two different domains from a browser prospective. I think you need to enable CORS support for domain `app.domain.com` in your Kentico web.config. 
You may try to add something like this to your web.config:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://app.mydomain.com" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```