# Setting the CurrentContact Cookie domain for sharing across Kentico sites

Tags: cookies, kentico

I am working in Kentico 11.  I have multiple sites in the same Kentico instance each hosted on subdomains of a primary domain (news.example.com, www.example.com).  I want to share the currentcontact cookie between those subdomains.  Currently each of the subdomains show that cookie originating from that specific sub.

How can I set it up so that the currentcontact cookie and its value is available across the subs?

Comment: Refer the following URL [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49760071/change-domain-of-kentico-currentcontact-cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49760071/change-domain-of-kentico-currentcontact-cookie) Hope this helps.

Comment: Check the this URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49760071/change-domain-of-kentico-currentcontact-cookie

Answer (score 0):

one approach is what Vasu had suggested where you can leverage the fact, that subdomain cookies can be shared to some extent, though browsers by default do try to separate even these to certain extent.

Another would be to create a so-called super-cookie which goes above domains (https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/122372/how-to-detect-inspect-and-delete-a-super-cookie-of-a-specific-website )

Than you can create your own implementation of ICurrentContactProvider or IContactPersistentStorage interfaces where GetPersistentContact or respectively GetExistingContact methods would look at other cookies or supercookie as well to track contact across domains.